# Docker port forwarding for nodejs app

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm having problems configuring docker for my nodejs app.

I have previously set up containers for both php and rails with port forwarding working flawlessly, but for this instance i can't seem to get it to work.

Running: `docker ps`, i get the following:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
a60f9c82d600        29c7d94a8c58        "/bin/sh -c 'npm s..."   5 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds        3000/tcp            romantic_albattani
```

As you can see I'm not getting the usual: `0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp` that I am expecting.

`docker-compose ps` gives:

```
Name   Command   State   Ports
------------------------------
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  volumes_from:
    - box
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"

box:
  image: busybox
  volumes:
    - /node_modules
```

My Docker file:

```
FROM node:8.7.0

# The base node image sets a very verbose log level.
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn

WORKDIR /tmp
COPY package.json /tmp/
RUN npm install

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN cp -a /tmp/node_modules /app/

#ENV PORT=3000
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm start
```

I'm running the command: `docker-compose up --build`

Any help at this point is appreciated.

I don't know if a docker inspect would be useful, but if so, tell me and i will also post it.

Edit: Changed my Dockerfile to follow the answer.

Comment: if you run docker logs -f a60f9c82d600 what are the logs of that container? also have you checked if the port is open and nothing else is listening on it?

Comment: @Sergiu: I get the following: `Error response from daemon: configured logging driver does not support reading`

Comment: then that's your problem :) container isn't running properly because your logs. I would start debugging from there

Comment: I will try and fix that and come back later with the results :)

Comment: `romantic_albattani` Is a random name. Docker compose does not use random names. Be sure that your compose container is not exiting. And kill that romantic stuff if you don't need it.

Comment: @Sergiu that is no a problem. He is using a different logging driver

Comment: @Robert: what do you mean "Docker compose does not use random names"? I haven't specified any name in my yml. Even when i try setting it with container_name nothing seams to happen.

One thing that might be a clue is that when i run `docker-compose ps` the result is empty.

Comment: `docker-compose` will name your containers as this: `<dir_name>_<service_name>_<number>`. For example: `myproject_web_1`, instead of what docker does by default (in your case romatic bla bla). So viewing that container, I can suspect that it is not being run by docker-compose (maybe you have run it in some other way?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `docker-compose.yml` file has bad formatting, since you are not getting any errors i will assume you pasted it here wrong, here is the version with the fixed indenting:

```
web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  volumes_from:
    - box
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"

box:
  image: busybox
  volumes:
    - /node_modules
```

Your `Dockerfile` has a bug, you are missing the `ENTRYPOINT` and/or `CMD` stanzas, instead you are using the `RUN` stanza with the wrong intent, here is a working `Dockerfile` with the fix applied:

```
FROM node:8.7.0

# The base node image sets a very verbose log level.
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn

WORKDIR /tmp
COPY package.json /tmp/
RUN npm install

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN cp -a /tmp/node_modules /app/

#ENV PORT=3000
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm start
```

Your `Dockerfile` halted the execution of `docker-compose` at the docker image building stage because of the `RUN npm start` which is a process that starts and listens until stopped (because you want it to start your node app and listen for connections) causing `docker-compose` to never finish the docker image creating step, let alone the other steps like creating the needed containers and finish the entire `docker-compose` runtime process.

In short:

When you use `RUN` it is meant to run a command do some work and return sometime to continue the building process, it should return and exit code of 0 and the process will move on to the next `Dockerfile` stanza, or return another exit code and the building process will fail with an error.

When you use `CMD` you tell the docker image what is the starting command of all the containers started from this image (it can also be overridden at run time with `docker run`). It is tightly related to the `ENTRYPOINT` stanza, but for basic usage you are safe with the default.

Further reading: [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint), [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) and [`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run)